# letter guessing game in python, cant replace letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a guessing game in python but I cant figure some stuff out. I have to enter a word and it will print a lot of spaces and the person is suppose to guess the word. It has to look like this after the word it's been typed. The user will enter a letter and is suppose to look like this for example (word is dog):

```
            >>Enter a letter:  a

            >> So far you have:

            >>      ***

            >>

            >>Enter a letter: o

            >> So far you have:

            >>      *o*
```

I almost have it figure out except that I can't put the last pieces together. Here is my program so far, I can't figure out how to replace the '*' with the correct letter.

```
def main():
print ("\n Word guess!")
print ("______________")


letters_guessed = []

# Read word 
word = input("\n Please Enter a word: ")
# print 100 spaces
print("\n" * 100)
# Storing the length of the word
word_length = len(word)
guess = '*' * word_length


while True:
    guess_letter = input ("Please guess a letter: ")
    if len(guess_letter) != 1:
        print ("Please guess one letter at a time")
    if guess_letter in letters_guessed:
        print ("\n You already guessed that letter, please try again")

    # Store words already guessed
    else:
        # Update already guessed characters 
        letters_guessed += guess_letter

        if guess_letter in word:
            print ("So far you have: ", guess)
            guess = guess_letter
            print(guess)







print("You won, the word is " + word)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a new string which uses the original letters if guessed and otherwise uses `*` for the unguessed letters, a quick way to do this is:

```
>>> word = 'dog'
>>> letters_guessed = ['o']
>>> you_have = ''.join(x if x in letters_guessed else '*' for x in word)
>>> print("So far you have: ", you_have)
So far you have:  *o*
```

Comment: this words but this is what is showing:Please guess a letter: a
So far you have:  ***a*
Please guess a letter: r
So far you have:  ****r
how can I keep it replaced?

Comment: You might be using `guessed_letter` instead of `letters_guessed`, I'll update the code to use the same variable name from yours.

Comment: Thank you! How would I display if they won the game?

Comment: `won = all(x in letters_guessed for x in word)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that strings are immutable. So you can't change a string, you can only make a new one based on the original one.

---

One way to do this is with slicing. For example:

```
>>> s = '****'
>>> s[:1] + 'P' + s[2:]
'*P**'
```

More generally:

```
>>> def replacechar(s, idx, ch):
...     return s[:idx] + ch + s[idx+1:]
>>> replacechar('****', 2, 'A')
'**A*'
```

---

Another way to do this is to use a list of characters instead of a string—because lists are mutable—and then just convert it to a string whenever you need to print it:

```
>>> guess = ['*'] * 4
>>> guess
['*', '*', '*', '*']
>>> ''.join(guess)
'****'
>>> guess[3] = 'M'
>>> guess
['*', '*', '*', 'M']
>>> ''.join(guess)
'***M'
```

---

Of course either way, you're going to need to know the index—or indexes—of the `*` to replace. So you can't just check `if guess_letter in word:`, you have to loop over calling something like `word.index(guess_letter)`.